# Batch script to pngcrush all files in all subfolders

Tags: image, optimization, batch-file, png

I have a folder structure with one main parent folder containing many subfolders, and in these some PNGs, something like:

```
.../data

.../data/013523/
.../data/345343/
.../data/395338/

.../data/013523/filex.png
.../data/013523/filey.png
.../data/345343/filea.png
.../data/345343/fileb.png
.../data/345343/filec.png
```

I'd like to crush all these PNGs with a Windows batch-script knowing only the location of the parent `data` folder (ie the folder names and png names are unknown, it should just crush all PNGs in all folders).

I took a look at [Drag and drop batch file for multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243240/drag-and-drop-batch-file-for-multiple-files) but this didn't seem to be quite what I was after.

Oh and no fancy naming options required, crushing in-place is fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well

```
for /r ...\data %%x in (*.png) do pngcrush "%%x"
```

should do it.

If the path to your `data` directory contains spaces somewhere, the following should work better, though:

```
pushd "...\data"
for /r %%x in (*.png) do pngcrush "%%x"
popd
```

Comment: Thanks will try it out shortly.