# Drag and drop batch file for multiple files?

Tags: batch-file

I am hoping to accomplish something similar to the below, but with pcutmp3:

[Drag and drop batch file for multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243240/drag-and-drop-batch-file-for-multiple-files)

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the additions Joey made as I don't usually do this, but I am wanting to drop multiple files (.cue) on a batch file and have it run more than once, which is what is happening with the following lines in the batch file:

```
@echo off
title pcutmp3
cd /d "F:\pcutmp3"
java -jar pcutmp3.jar --cue %1 --dir "F:\Test"
pause
exit
```

I've tried adapting Joey's code... but to no avail (I have no clue what I'm doing)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 10):

```
@echo off
title pcutmp3
cd /d "F:\pcutmp3"

:again
if "%~1" == "" goto done

java -jar pcutmp3.jar --cue "%~1" --dir "F:\Test"

shift
goto again

:done
pause
exit
```

This is your basic "Eat all the arguments" loop. The important part is the `shift` keyword, which eats `%1`, and shifts all the arguments down by one (so that `%2` becomes `%1`, `%3` becomes `%2`, etc)

So, if you run it like so:

```
pcutmp3.bat a b c
```

It will call java like so:

```
java -jar pcutmp3.jar --cue "a" --dir "F:\Test"
java -jar pcutmp3.jar --cue "b" --dir "F:\Test"
java -jar pcutmp3.jar --cue "c" --dir "F:\Test"
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your help! I was running the batch by simply dropping .cue files on top of it. After trying what you said I'm simply getting `/dir_path/test.cue"" unexpected at this time` Not exactly sure why...? Thanks again!

Comment: My bad! I forgot that Explorer will quote file names. Basically, it was going `if ""somefile\blahbah"" == ""`, and it wasn't liking all the extra quotes. I've updated the script to strip the quotes properly. Also, with this change, the batch file is no longer DOS compatible :(

Comment: ok, yes this definitely worked. I appreciate your help hugely with this. Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

Dealing with `%1`, shift or `%*` could fail with drag&drop, because the explorer is not very smart, when it creates the command line.

Files like `Cool&stuff.cue` are not quoted by the explorer so you get a cmdline like
`pcutmp3.bat Cool&stuff.cue`

So in `%1` is only `Cool` even in `%*` is only `Cool`, but after the pcutmp3.bat ends, cmd.exe tries to execute a `stuff.cue`.

To handle with this stuff you could use this, it catch all filenames by using the `cmdcmdline` variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set index=0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem *** Take the cmd-line, remove all until the first parameter
rem *** Copy cmdcmdline without any modifications, as cmdcmdline has some strange behaviour
set "params=!cmdcmdline!"
set "params=!params:~0,-1!"
set "params=!params:*" =!"
echo params: !params!
rem Split the parameters on spaces but respect the quotes
for %%G IN (!params!) do (
    for %%# in (!index!) do (
        endlocal
        set /a index+=1
        set "item_%%#=%%~G"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
)

set /a max=index-1

rem list the parameters
for /L %%n in (0,1,!max!) DO (
  echo %%n #!item_%%n!#
)
pause

REM ** The exit is important, so the cmd.exe doesn't try to execute commands after ampersands
exit
```

Btw. there is a line limit for drag&drop operations of ~2048 characters, in spite of the "standard" batch line limit of 8191 characters.

Comment: [I filed a report regarding quoting files with `&` in their names](https://aka.ms/AA21ws3). Hopefully someone will see it and fix

Comment: Hi jeb, is it possible to expand `%%n` to get the path? Like so: `%%~pn` I tried that and it returns: `ECHO is off.` Here's what I tried `echo !item_%%~pn!`

Comment: @StephenSherry It's possible to expand `%%~pn` but in this code `%%n` contains numbers only, therefore a path doesn't make sense. But you probably want to get the path of the item. But better ask a new question with a reference to this question/answer when useful

Comment: This works great until I drag a file with a ! (exclamation mark).  Does anyone have a good way to allow ! in the dragged file name?

Comment: @JG1212 I add exclamation support

Comment: @jeb  This revision works perfectly with both & and !.  You are amazing!!

Comment: Great solution but doesn't work if the file has `,`, `;` or `=` (unless the filename has spaces, in which case it will be quoted and those characters won't act as delimiters).

Comment: @Bangaio Yes, this is an effect of the splitting at `for %%G IN (!params!) do `. You can solve it with the AutoRun.bat from [Handling ; (semi-colon) in filenames with this drag and drop routine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59974834/463115)

Answer (score 1):

If you need split the filename out of a full path, try this:

```
...
for %%a IN (!params!) do (
    for %%# in (!index!) do (
        endlocal
        set /a index+=1
        set "item_%%#=%%~a"
        set "DISK_%%#=%%~da"
        set "Folder_%%#=%%~dpa"
        set "FullFolder_%%#=%%~fa"
        set "FileName_%%#=%%~nxa"
        set "LastName_%%#=%%~na"
        set "Ext_%%#=%%~xa"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
)

set /a max=index-1

echo ---------
rem list the parameters
for /L %%n in (0,1,!max!) DO (
    set MYDIR=!item_%%n!
    set DISK=!DISK_%%n!
    set Folder=!Folder_%%n!
    set FullFolder=!FullFolder_%%n!
    set FileName=!FileName_%%n!
    set LastName=!LastName_%%n!
    set Ext=!Ext_%%n!
    echo !MYDIR!
    echo !DISK!
    echo !Folder!
    echo !FullFolder!
    echo !FileName!
    echo !LastName!
    echo !Ext!
)
echo ---------
```

And output

---

```
D:\test\test2\file.txt
D:
D:\test\
D:\test\test2\file.txt
file.txt
file
.txt
---------
```