# Drag & Drop folder in a batch to be read in java application

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm kinda new in Java and even more in batch, I'm working on a little program that auto check bunch of specific files in a folder, however at this point, I need to use a Scanner in Java to read the path of the folder I want to check and I wonder what would I need to just have to drag and drop the folder into my batch to execute this application

Here is the start of my application with the scanner

```java
public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Locators folder : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String path = sc.next();
        sc.close();
        File[] folders = new File(path).listFiles();
```

And here is the batch even if it won't bring much info

```
@ECHO off

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe" -jar "E:\Hugo\Documents\_Quadrica\afc.jar"
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on "drag and drop the folder into my batch"? Do you mean you want to drag a folder in desktop GUI and drop it on .jar file in order to run in?

Comment: Yes kinda, in the windows explorer, I would like to drag a folder, drop it into the batch file (Also in Windows explorer) that run my jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `Scanner` to get the path.
When you drag a file (or folder) onto your batch file, it becomes a command line argument to your batch file, so all you need to do is add `%1` to the end of the *java* command in the batch file, i.e.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2\bin\java.exe" -jar "E:\Hugo\Documents\_Quadrica\afc.jar" "%1"
```

Note: Enclose `%1` in double quotes is necessary if the path contains spaces. Also note that it will not work if the path contains unusual characters like `&`, for example. Please refer to [Batch file Copy using %1 for drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786623/batch-file-copy-using-1-for-drag-and-drop)

Then in your java code, the path is actually in the `args` parameter to method `main()`, so your java code should be...

```java
public static void main (String[] args) {
    if (args.length > 0) {
        System.out.println("Locators folder: " + args[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use `"%~1"` rather than `"%1"`, since paths including spaces already arrive quoted, and the `~` removes them at first, so you avoid quoting an already quoted path…

Comment: @aschipfl Or simply drop the double quotes since they are unnecessary?

Comment: No, since they protect spaces and some special characters…