# Is a single exit at the bottom of a batch file redundant?

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on some Windows `.bat` files that have been around for a long time. On their last line, they have a single `exit` statement without arguments.

This appears to be completely redundant to me. Is there any valid reason for their presence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `exit` withoput `/b` option will exit batch file **and** the cmd.exe instance.

When you start the batch file by starting it from the explorer, there is not difference,
but when you start the batch file from a cmd window, the window closes when the batch file executes the `exit`.

Normally you should avoid this, as it's annoying behaviour, you can't build another batch file calling this type of files, as the `exit` also cancels the calling batch file.

```
call myAnnoyingBatch.bat
echo This won't be displayed anymore
```

I only know one good reason for using `exit` at the end of a script.
When you build a [drag&drop script that should be bullet proof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192427/463115) , you need an exit to avoid problems with some filenames like `cat&dog.png`

Comment: Ah, so there is a difference, but indeed, that would be annoying and I can't imagine why they were made this way, so I'll just remove them.

Comment: By the way, some of the files do get called from an overarching file, and it doesn't cause the issue you described. However, it's not using `call` but `start /B /wait`. Could there be any reason for that, other than to explicitly avoid the problem of the `exit` in the subfile?

Comment: I see `call` runs the script in the current process while `start` runs a new one (equivalent to _sourcing_ vs _executing_ in bash), with the expected results regarding variable lifetime and such. But variables are not used here, so not a factor. That also explains why exit in a `call`ed file would exit the calling process: because there's just the one process.

Comment: `start /b /wait` starts a parallel command, the output shall be in the same window (`/b`) and wait until the parallel command finishes '(`/wait`). That could be replaced by a simple `cmd /c`. Or even with a `CALL` when you remove the `exit`, then the other scripts can also change environment variables of the caller context