# Handling ; (semi-colon) in filenames with this drag and drop routine

Tags: batch-file

Consider these filenames.

```
; f - Copy.txt
;f.txt
f - Copy ;- Copy.txt
f - Copy.txt
```

I've got this code which resolves the `&` symbol in any files with this answer: [Drag and drop batch file for multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243240/drag-and-drop-batch-file-for-multiple-files/5370380#5370380)

```
@echo off
title %~nx0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem Take the cmd-line, remove all until the first parameter
set "params=!cmdcmdline:~0,-1!"
set "params=!params:*" =!"
set count=0
rem Split the parameters on spaces but respect the quotes
for %%G IN (!params!) do (
  set /a count+=1
  set "item_!count!=%%~G"
  rem echo !count! %%~G
)
for /l %%c in (1,1,!count!) DO (
for /f "delims=;" %%A in ("!item_%%c!") do (
  echo path: %%~dpA
  echo file: %%~A
  )
)
pause
rem ** The exit is important, so the cmd.exe doesn't try to execute commands after ampersands
exit
```

If I drag the files to the batch file it uses `;` as the delimiter resulting in undesired results.

To get around this with the `for /f` you can do the following below but I'm at a loss as to how to incorporate that fix into the drag and drop code above.

---

There's an issue with the `for /f` whereby it uses `;` as the delimiter also but this can be resolved with (This trick can be [found here](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html))
`for /f tokens^=*^ delims^=^ eol^=^¬ %%A in ('dir "%cd%" /a-d /b') do ( echo %%~A )`

Which results in:

```
; f - Copy.txt
;f.txt
f - Copy ;- Copy.txt
f - Copy.txt
```

as opposed to:
`for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('dir "%cd%" /a-d /b') do ( echo %%~A )`

Which results in:

```
f - Copy ;- Copy.txt
f - Copy.txt
```

How can I fix this issue with the drag and drop code?

**Edit:** I'm getting kinda close with this.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f tokens^=*^ delims^=^ ^ eol^=^¬ %%A in (""!%*!"") do ( echo "%%~fA" )
```

**Edit: (more examples)** Another example that can extend the dropped items to any those at this link: [Extended Filename syntax to %* with the following workaround](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html). This also works in a half-hearted sort of way.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (%*) do ( call :FIX "%%~A" )
pause
:FIX
SET _params=!%*!
CALL :sub "%_params%"
GOTO :eof
:: Now display just the filename and extension (not path)
:sub
ECHO "%~nx1"
:: All of these returns are when each file (one at a time) is dragged to the batch file.
rem folder name , goes = here...        works      returns "folder name , goes = here..."
rem ; f - copy.txt                      works      returns "; f - copy.txt"
rem ;f.txt                              doesn't    returns "." ""
rem a.txt                               works      return  "a.txt"
rem b.txt                               works      return  "b.txt"
rem c.txt                               works      return  "c.txt"
rem cool&stuff.png                      doesn't    returns "Cool""
rem copy = copy.txt                     works      returns "copy = copy.txt"
rem f - copy - copy.txt                 works      returns "f - copy - copy.txt"
rem f - copy ,- copy - copy.txt         works      returns "f - copy ,- copy - copy.txt"
rem f - copy ;- copy.txt                works      returns "f - copy ;- copy.txt"
rem f - copy.txt                        works      returns "f - copy.txt "
rem f - copy1.txt                       works      returns "f - copy1.txt"
rem FILENAME WITH & IN IT!! - COPY.TXT  doesn't    returns "FILENAME WITH & IN IT - COPY.TXT""
rem FILENAME WITH & IN IT!!.TXT         doesn't    returns "FILENAME WITH & IN IT.TXT""
```

Comment: The problem is not only the `;`, it's any delimiter `,;=`, because the windows `drag&drop` doesn't enclose them into quotes. You can't solve it with a single `FOR /F` loop. But it can be solved with a bit replace magic

Answer (score 3):

I've found a thread here that addresses this issue and as far as I can see, works with any special characters.

Big thanks to user *aGerman* on that forum... *All credit goes to him.*

**Link to that thread:**

[Solved  How to escape special characters on InputFile with Drag and Drop ?](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9301&hilit=drag+and+drop)

**Other useful links:**

[Simplest loop to perform actions on x dragged files?](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5479)

['Pretty print' windows %PATH% variable - how to split on ';' in CMD shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471556/pretty-print-windows-path-variable-how-to-split-on-in-cmd-shell/7940444#7940444)

[Drag and drop batch file for multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243240/drag-and-drop-batch-file-for-multiple-files/5370380#5370380)

```
@echo off &setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "params=!cmdcmdline:~,-1!"
set "params=!params:*" =!"

if "!params!"=="" exit

endlocal&set "params=%params:"=""%"
set "params=%params:^=^^%"
set "params=%params:&=^&%"
set "params=%params: =^ ^ %"
set params=%params:""="%
set "params=%params:"=""Q%"
set "params=%params:  ="S"S%"
set "params=%params:^ ^ = %"
set "params=%params:""="%"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "params=!params:"Q=!"

for %%i in ("!params:"S"S=" "!") do (
  if "!!"=="" endlocal
  REM only files ...
  if not exist "%%~i\" (
  set "file_folder=%%~i"
  call :proc
  )
  )

echo ready.
pause
exit

:proc
echo process "%file_folder%" here ...
goto :eof
```

Comment: Impressive. The pretty print technique was exactly the *replace magic* I meant :-)

Comment: All credit to user **aGerman** on the dostips forum. Yes, there's also a way to use [freecommander](https://freecommander.com/en/summary/) the explorer to work for all cases. Even `C:\nospacepath\folder\peter&(mary).txt` which failed here but works in that. I was too stubborn to admit defeat with this and have spent far too long on it. The FC method just needs `%ActivSel%` to be passed to the batch file as param `%1` and then wrap each with quotes enabled in the Define favourite toolbars settings.

Comment: `a&(b).txt` is problematic, because it`s parsed to `a & (b).txt`, the `a &` part is okay, but the `(b).txt` creates a syntax error, as the `.txt` is directly appended to a command block. And the syntax error is detected before the batch file even starts. It works if you drag a second file *before* with name `d5_& REM #`

Comment: But even the `A&()` problematic can be solved with a small hack.

Comment: It would be interesting if that just takes another line or two to fix. I don't think there's any point of creating a new thread. If you have a solution, I'd love to hear it. As this would solve the problem completely.

Comment: Sorry, it's a nasty hack, not one or two lines (but still only 300 lines). I add [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59974834/463115)

Answer (score 1):

As jeb noted, the main problem comes from a file such as `;f.txt` not being enclosed in double-quotes. [Ste's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59934228/2096401) is probably better, since it doesn't involve "eating" chunks of `params`, but as I was most of the way through revising my original attempt when that was posted, I decided to finish it and offer it as another approach.

```
@echo off
title %~nx0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem Take the cmd-line, remove all until the first parameter
set "params=!cmdcmdline:~0,-1!"
set "params=::!params:*" =!"
set count=0
:loop
  for /f usebackq^ tokens^=1^ delims^=^" %%A in ('!params:~2!') do (
    REM The second test below tests if "params" started with a double-quote.
    REM Taken from https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=850#p850
    if "%%A" == " " (
      set "params=::!params:~3!"
    ) else if [!params:~2^,1!]==[^"] (
      call :proc "%%A"
      set "params=::!params:::"%%A"=!"
    ) else (
      set "spaces=%%A"
      set "spaces=^"!spaces: =^" ^"!^""
      for %%B in (!spaces!) do if not "%%~B" == "" (
        call :proc "%%~B"
      )
      set "params=::!params:::%%A=!"
    )
  )
  if not "!params!" == "::" goto :loop
  pause
  exit

:proc
    echo process "%~1" here ...
    goto :eof
```

Dropping the above four files (plus `f ; & ; f.txt` and a few others for good measure) into this script produces:

```
process "C:\X\Dev\Semicolons\q" here ...
process "C:\X\Dev\Semicolons\q q q" here ...
process "C:\X\Dev\Semicolons\; f - Copy.txt" here ...
process "C:\X\Dev\Semicolons\;f.txt" here ...
process "C:\X\Dev\Semicolons\f - Copy ;- Copy.txt" here ...
process "C:\X\Dev\Semicolons\f - Copy.txt" here ...
process "C:\X\Dev\Semicolons\f ; & ; f.txt" here ...
process "C:\X\Dev\Semicolons\f.safe.txt" here ...
process "C:\X\Dev\Semicolons\f.safe2.txt" here ...
Press any key to continue . . .
```

### Notes

- The drag-and-drop interface wraps *some* unsafe filenames in double-quotes (e.g. those containing spaces) but not all (e.g. those containing `;`), Thus we cannot just use `for %%a in (!params!)` to process all files.
- Instead, the basic idea is to split the `params` variable at the first double-quote (if present), process that "chunk", then remove it from `params` and repeat.
- If the chunk is a space (`" "`) then we simply remove it (this can happen as part of processing the other chunks).
- If `params` started with a double-quote when the current chunk was extracted, then it represents a single file and it is processed (`call :proc`). That filename (with its surrounding double-quotes) is then removed from `params` and we loop back.
- If `params` *didn't* start with a double-quote, then we have one *or more* filenames in the current chunk. We *know* that none of them contain spaces (because otherwise they would be wrapped in double-quotes), but they *might* contain other "problem" characters such as `;`. Therefore, we wrap each space-delimited component of the chunk in double-quotes (turning `aaa bbb ccc` into `"aaa" "bbb" "ccc"`) and use a simple `for` loop to process each one. (The `""` test is because there can be stray spaces at the beginning or end of the chunk). After all file(s) have been processed, the original chunk is removed from `params` and we loop back.
- The `::` prefix prepended to `params` (and skipped in the main `for` command) is to catch a particular issue if one file name is a prefix of another (e.g. `C:\Files\Q` and `C:\Files\Q Q`). Without the `::`s, when removing `C:\Files\Q` from `params`, the replace-all-occurrences nature of CMD means the second file's name is mangled. Keeping `params` prefixed with `::` (which can never occur in a valid file) stops this from happening.
- The script should work for any number of files (up to the roughly 8,192-character limit for the original command-line).

Comment: This only works for optimal test cases :-) Try it with simple filenames `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`. I don't think that it can be solved with a FOR/F loop and delimiters

Comment: @jeb You're right... I just realised it needs at least every other file to be enclosed in double-quotes... back to drawing board!

Comment: Thanks for helping. There will be no limit to the number of files I would like to drop. Is there a hard limit of 26 with this? I'll update the question with more examples.

Comment: @Ste Regard the above as a "work in progress"... as jeb noted, it won't work with "simple" files that don't need any double-quotes. _**In passing**_ even with "normal" files, there's a hard limit on the length of the command-line of a bit less than 8,192 bytes. Depending on the depth of the paths being dragged, this puts an upper limit on the number of files that can be processed.

Comment: Oh, I've found what looks like a great solution. And if I `cd /d` into any found directories, I can then run the process as per normal. It's just the initial drag and dropped files and folders that get chewed up. Here's the **How to escape special characters on InputFile with Drag and Drop ?** [dostips thread here](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9301&p=60445&hilit=drag+and+drop#p60441)

Comment: @Ste Well done... that solution looks best, although being "bloody-minded" I've finished adapting my original approach (splitting on double-quotes) so that it shouldn't be limited to 26 items or less (and, as jeb pointed out, it should also handle multiple files that don't _need_ double-quotes).

Comment: Thanks for finishing that off. I tested against my _simply weird filenames_ and all work fine apart from files with `=` in them, such as `folder name , goes = here` and `copy = copy.txt`. With the answer I found the only one that doesn't work is `C:/nospaces/peter &(mary).txt` but there's literally nothing sent to the command line with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set "params=!cmdcmdline:~,-1!" & echo !params! & pause
` so nothing can be done in this instance AFAIK.

Comment: Some more challenges `d1_equal=yes` (loops forever), `d2_caret^^double`, `d3_missing!bang!` Btw. When you test d2 and d3 together, then d2 works!

Comment: @jeb I'll probably just stick to not naming my files like that :-)

Comment: @TripeHound That's a pity, I name 90% of my files like that

Answer (score 1):

My own version to solve all drag&drop problems:

Can handle any filenames, like

> d1_;,=
>   d2_four    spaces
>   d3_One&Amp
>   d4_Amp&with space

But there is still a strong problem, filenames like `a&()` can't be handled by the drag.bat, because the filename creates a syntax error even before the batch file is called.

But with a nasty hack it can be solved, then even the hard ones works!

> d5_syntax&()error

cmd.exe can start an AutoRun (batch) command, if registered.
This AutoRun batch file gets no arguments, but the complete command in `cmdcmdline`.
I simply parse that data and if necessary I rebuild new quoted arguments (only 300 lines).
For modifying the registry entry use

```
AutoRun --show
AutoRun --install
AutoRun --remove
```

**drag.bat**

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem *** Take the cmd-line, remove all until the first parameter
rem *** Copy cmdcmdline without any modifications, as cmdcmdline has some strange behaviour
set "params=!cmdcmdline!"
set "params=!params:~0,-1!"
set "params=!params:*" =!"
call :fn_$arg_parser params

REM ** FOR /L %%# in (0 1 !arg#-1!) DO (
REM **  echo arg%%# = '!arg%%#!'
REM ** )

set count=0

rem Split the parameters on spaces but respect the quotes
set "params=!params:^;^=""S!"
for %%G IN (!params:^;^=""S!) do (
  set /a count+=1
  set "_item=%%~G"
  set "item_!count!=!_item:""=;!"
  rem echo !count! %%~G
)

rem list the parameters
for /L %%n in (1,1,!count!) DO (
  echo arg%%n #!item_%%n!#
)
pause > NUL

REM ** The exit is important, so the cmd.exe doesn't try to execute commands after ampersands
exit


:fn_$arg_parser arg_line
REM *** @TODO: ENDLOCAL all arg-... variables
::: Output arg0, ..., arg and arg#
::: arg0 ... arg contains unquoted arguments
::: an argument that contains only one quote (last character in line) is treated as quoted  arg=" -> arg=, arg.quoted=1
::: arg0.quoted contains 1 if the argument was quoted
::: \ escapes the next character (also inside quotes), can escape delimiters outside quotes, can escape quotes
::: Only \" is replaced to a single quote ", all other \ are unchanged

(set^ arg_line=!%1!)
call :strlen arg_len arg_line
set /a arg_len-=1

set "quoted="
rem set "escapeChar="   --- "Say: \"Hello\" to frank\n"
set /a arg#=0
set "arg0="
for /L %%I in (0 1 !arg_len!) DO (
    for %%# in (!arg#!) DO  (
        set "char=!arg_line:~%%I,1!"
        set "isDelim="

        if "!escapeChar!!char!" == ^""" set "quoted=!quoted:~,0!"

        REM echo %%I: "!char!" quote: !quote!
        %= only outside quotes =%
        %= check if char is a delim =%
        FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%D in ("isDelim!char!NO") DO (
            if "%%D" == "isDelim" (
                set isDelim=1
            )
        )

        REM *** Split arguments by not escaped delimiter
        if "!isDelim!,!quoted!,!escapeChar!" == "1,," (
            REM *** Finalize arg, test if arg is quoted
            if defined arg%%# (
                set arg%%#.quoted=
                REM echo    #in %%# "!arg%%#:~,1!!arg%%#:~-1!"
                if "!arg%%#:~,1!!arg%%#:~-1!" == """" (
                    if "!arg%%#:~-2,-1!" NEQ "\" (
                        set arg%%#.quoted=1
                        set "arg%%#=!arg%%#:~1,-1!"
                    )
                )
                if defined arg%%# (
                    set ^"arg%%#=!arg%%#:"\"="!"
                )
                set /a arg#+=1
            )
        )

        if defined escapeChar (
            set "escapeChar="
            if "!char!" EQU ^""" (
                REM *** Replace escaped quotes with "\" that can be safely detected and replaced later
                set "char="\""
            ) ELSE IF defined isDelim (
                set "isDelim="
            ) ELSE (
                set "char=\!char!"
            )
        ) ELSE if "!char!" == "\" set "escapeChar=\"

        if defined quoted set "isDelim="

        REM *** Append char to arg
        if "!isDelim!!escapeChar!" == "" (
            set "arg%%#=!arg%%#!!char!"
        )
    )
)

for %%# in (!arg#!) DO (
    REM *** Last character is \
    if defined escapeChar (
        set "arg%%#=!arg%%#!\"
    )

    REM *** Duplicated code
    REM *** Finalize arg, test if arg is quoted
    if defined arg%%# (
        set arg%%#.quoted=
        REM echo out %%# "!arg%%#:~,1!!arg%%#:~-1!"
        if "!arg%%#:~,1!!arg%%#:~-1!" == """" (
            if "!arg%%#:~-2,-1!" NEQ "\" (
                set arg%%#.quoted=1
                set "arg%%#=!arg%%#:~1,-1!"
            )
        )
        if defined arg%%# (
            set ^"arg%%#=!arg%%#:"\"="!"
        )
        set /a arg#+=1
    )
)
REM *** Create a helper variable with name "arg#-1"
set /a tmp=!arg#!-1
set "arg#-1=!tmp!"

exit /b
::: detector line %~* *** FATAL ERROR: missing parenthesis or exit /b
:strlen  
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
    if defined tmp (
        set "len=1"
        for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
            if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
                set /a "len+=%%P"
                set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
            )
        )
    ) ELSE (
        set len=0
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

**AutoRun.bat**

```
@echo off
REM *** To enable this script, call it by  --install

REM *** To see the current values
REM *** reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
REM *** reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun

REM *** To delete the keys
REM *** reg DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
REM *** reg DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM *** ALWAYS make a copy of the complete CMDCMDLINE, else you destroy the originial!!!
set "_ccl_=!cmdcmdline!"
echo(>CON

REM *** %1 contains only data, when the script itself was called from the command line
if "%~1" NEQ "" (
    goto :direct_call
)
REM echo #0 '!_ccl_!' > CON
REM *** The check is necessary to distinguish between a new cmd.exe instance for a user or for a "FOR /F" sub-command
if "!_ccl_:~1,-2!" == "!comspec!" (
    REM ***** INTERACTIVE ****

    echo %DATE% %TIME% comspec >> "%~dp0\started.log"
    FOR %%M in ("%~dp0\cmdMacros.mac") DO (
        endlocal    
        echo ********************************************************************
        echo * AutoRun executed from "%~f0"
        if exist "%%~M" (
            doskey /macrofile="%%~M"
            echo * Macros loaded from "%%~M"
        ) ELSE (
            echo * Macrofile missing at "%%~M"
        )
        echo ********************************************************************
    )
    REM set "path=%path%;%~dp0"

    SET "BATLIB=C:\Project\BatchLibrary"

    call cd /D "%%BATLIB%%"
) ELSE (
    REM *** This is a FOR command, a call by an explorer click or a drag & drop operation

    REM *** Try to detect a PROBLEMATIC Drag&Drop operation, if it has the format `%comspec% /c ""`
    REM *** It's only problematic when there is one & in the data
    REM *** But it's not bullet proof, FOR /F in ('""C:\temp\myfile.bat" C:\temp\file&second.bat"') can't be distinguished

    REM *** First check, that the cmdline starts with `%comspec% /c ""....`
    if "!_ccl_!" NEQ "!_ccl_:*/c ""=#!" if "!comspec! /c ""!_ccl_:*/c ""=!" == "!_ccl_!" (
        REM *** Only handle it, if there is at least one & and no pipe |
        if "!_ccl_!" NEQ "!_ccl_:&=!" if "!_ccl_!" EQU "!_ccl_:|=!" (
            call :DRAG_and_drop
            %DEBUG_DRAG% echo # BACK from DRAG_and_drop
        )
    )
    REM *** Leaving now
    REM *** This is a "FOR /F" sub-command 
    REM *** or a "harmless" drag&drop 
    REM *** or the second run of a problematic drag&drop
    REM echo %DATE% %TIME% internal "!_ccl_!" >> "%~dp0\started.log"
    endlocal
)

exit /b

:DRAG_and_drop
REM *** This results into recursive execution of this script
REM *** Be sure, that it's not an endless recursion

REM *** Remove the front 
REM set "_ccl_=!_ccl_:&=+!"
set "_ccl_=!_ccl_:~0,-1!"
set "_ccl_=!_ccl_:*/c "=!"
set "DEBUG_DRAG=REM " 

%DEBUG_DRAG% echo #A '!_ccl_!' > CON

call :arg_parser argv _ccl_ 

REM *** Check if there is at least one unquoted, problematic &
REM *** This arg must not have spaces
set "isDragAndDrop="

if defined argv.onlySingleSpace (
    set "isDragAndDrop=1"
    set "problematic="
    set "args="
    FOR /L %%# in (0 1 !argv#-1!) DO (
        set "arg=!argv[%%#]!"
        REM *** Check if it's an absolute path
        FOR /F "tokens=1,*" %%1 in (": !arg!") DO (
            if "%%~f2" NEQ "%%~2" (
                set "isDragAndDrop="
                %DEBUG_DRAG% echo *** 'NO PATH' !arg! NEQ %%~f2 > CON
                exit /b
            )
        )

        if defined argv[%%#].quoted (
            set "arg="!arg!""
        ) ELSE (
            REM *** If not quoted but contains a &

            if "!arg!" NEQ "!arg:&=!" (
                if "!arg:~1,2!" EQU ":\" (
                    set "arg="!arg!""
                    set "problematic=1"             
                ) ELSE (
                    REM *** This can't be drap&drop, because arg doesn't begin with ":\"
                    set "isDragAndDrop="
                    %DEBUG_DRAG% echo *** NO DRIVE '!arg!' > CON
                    exit /b
                )
            )
        )
        set "args=!args!!arg! "
    )
    set "args=!args:~,-1!"
)

if not defined problematic (
    set "isDragAndDrop="
    REM echo *** 'problematic = 0' > CON
)

if defined isDragAndDrop (
REM ECHO *** HANDLE isDragAndDrop *** > CON
REM echo *** '!args!' > CON
    REM *** The TWO SPACES between comspec and /c are essential!
    REM *** The AutoRun script detects the recursion call by this difference
    (
        endlocal
        %comspec%  /c ^"%args%"
    )

    REM *** Back from the dragDrop script
    REM *** EXIT to avoid a second call
    exit
)

REM *** This is the path for unproblematic content
REM *** Or it was detected, that this isn't a drap&drop operation
exit /b

:direct_call
if "%~1" == "--install" (
    reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v "AutoRun" /t REG_SZ /d "%~f0"
    exit /b
) 

if "%~1" == "--show" (  
    reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun
    exit /b
)

if "%~1" == "--remove" (
    reg DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
)
exit /b

:arg_parser  arg_line
REM *** @TODO: ENDLOCAL all arg-... variables
::: Output arg0, ..., arg and arg#
::: arg0 ... arg contains unquoted arguments
::: an argument that contains only one quote (last character in line) is treated as quoted  arg=" -> arg=, arg.quoted=1
::: arg0.quoted contains 1 if the argument was quoted
::: \ escapes the next character (also inside quotes), can escape delimiters outside quotes, can escape quotes
::: Only \" is replaced to a single quote ", all other \ are unchanged

set "var=%1"
(set^ arg_line=!%2!)
call :strlen arg_len arg_line
set /a %var%_len-=1

set "quoted="
rem set "escapeChar="   --- "Say: \"Hello\" to frank\n"
set /a %var%#=0
set "%var%[0]="
set "%var%.onlySingleSpace=1"
for /L %%I in (0 1 !arg_len!) DO (
    for %%# in (!%var%#!) DO  (
        set "char=!arg_line:~%%I,1!"
        set "isDelim="

        if "!escapeChar!!char!" == ^""" set "quoted=!quoted:~,0!"

        REM echo %%I: "!char!" quote: !quote!
        %= only outside quotes =%
        %= check if char is a delim =%
        if not defined quoted (
            FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims= " %%D in ("isDelim!char!NO") DO (
                if "%%D" == "isDelim" (
                    set isDelim=1
                    if "!arg_line:~%%I,2!" == "  " (
                        %DEBUG_DRAG% echo ##### NOT onlySingleSpace > CON
                        set "%var%.onlySingleSpace="
                    )
                )
            )
        )

        REM *** Split arguments by not escaped delimiter
        if "!isDelim!,!quoted!,!escapeChar!" == "1,," (
            REM *** Finalize arg, test if arg is quoted
            if defined %var%[%%#] (
                set %var%[%%#].quoted=
                REM echo    #in %%# "!%var%[%%#]:~,1!!%var%[%%#]:~-1!"
                if "!%var%[%%#]:~,1!!%var%[%%#]:~-1!" == """" (
                    if "!%var%[%%#]:~-2,-1!" NEQ "\" (
                        set %var%[%%#].quoted=1
                        set "%var%[%%#]=!%var%[%%#]:~1,-1!"
                    )
                )
                REM * NOT USED HERE * if defined %var%[%%#] (
                REM * NOT USED HERE *   set ^"%var%[%%#]=!%var%[%%#]:"\"="!"
                REM * NOT USED HERE * )
                set /a %var%#+=1
            )
        )

        REM * NOT USED HERE * if defined escapeChar (
        REM * NOT USED HERE *   set "escapeChar="
        REM * NOT USED HERE *   if "!char!" EQU ^""" (
        REM * NOT USED HERE *       REM *** Replace escaped quotes with "\" that can be safely detected and replaced later
        REM * NOT USED HERE *       set "char="\""
        REM * NOT USED HERE *   ) ELSE IF defined isDelim (
        REM * NOT USED HERE *       set "isDelim="
        REM * NOT USED HERE *   ) ELSE (
        REM * NOT USED HERE *       set "char=\!char!"
        REM * NOT USED HERE *   )
        REM * NOT USED HERE * ) ELSE if "!char!" == "\" set "escapeChar=\"

        if defined quoted set "isDelim="

        REM *** Append char to arg
        if "!isDelim!!escapeChar!" == "" (
            set "%var%[%%#]=!%var%[%%#]!!char!"
        )
    )
)

for %%# in (!%var%#!) DO (
    REM *** Last character is \
    if defined escapeChar (
        set "%var%[%%#]=!%var%[%%#]!\"
    )

    REM *** Duplicated code
    REM *** Finalize arg, test if arg is quoted
    if defined %var%[%%#] (
        set %var%[%%#].quoted=
        if "!%var%[%%#]:~,1!!%var%[%%#]:~-1!" == """" (
            if "!%var%[%%#]:~-2,-1!" NEQ "\" (
                set %var%[%%#].quoted=1
                set "%var%[%%#]=!%var%[%%#]:~1,-1!"
            )
        )
        REM * NOT USED HERE * if defined %var%[%%#] (
        REM * NOT USED HERE *   set ^"%var%[%%#]=!%var%[%%#]:"\"="!"
        REM * NOT USED HERE * )
        set /a %var%#+=1
    )
)
REM *** Create a helper variable with name "arg#-1"
set /a tmp=!%var%#!-1
set "%var%#-1=!tmp!"

exit /b
::: detector line %~* *** FATAL ERROR: missing parenthesis or exit /b
:strlen  
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
    if defined tmp (
        set "len=1"
        for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
            if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
                set /a "len+=%%P"
                set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
            )
        )
    ) ELSE (
        set len=0
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```