# Drag and Drop a Folder in DOS Batch Commands

Tags: drag-and-drop, batch-file

I have a folder named `Images` and I have a `Run.exe`. Now when I drag and drop the `Images` folder on the `Run.exe`, it will execute the program.

Please help me with some good working example ASAP so that I can complete the same in time. I have only 2 days left to complete this. Would be great if someone could help me in this issue.

Comment: For an urgent question, yours is a bit too unclear. For instance, what does `Run.exe` have to do with batch commands that your title speaks about? However, you could start by having a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243240/drag-and-drop-batch-file-for-multiple-files "Drag and drop batch file for multiple files?"), which at first sight seems more or less close to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear to me. Did you say you want to create a batch file which would execute a command when you drag and drop the Images folder on the cmd window? In that case:

```
@echo off
cls
echo:Drag and drop the folder here:
set /p input=
rem Press enter after drag and drop.
rem X:\Y\Z\Images would be your Images folder.
if %input% == X:\Y\Z\Images goto :f
:f
rem The command to be executed goes below.
```