# Multiple Image conversion using ImageMagick

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick-convert

Problem: I want to be able to convert multiple images at a time by simply dragging multiple images onto my batch file.

Here's my programming code because I am resizing EACH image:

```
convert "%1" -thumbnail 50x -unsharp 1.5x1.2+1.0+0.10 "%~p1%~n1"
convert "%1" -thumbnail 80x -unsharp 1.5x1.2+1.0+0.10 "%~p1%~n1"
convert "%1" -thumbnail 120x -unsharp 1.5x1.2+1.0+0.10 "%~p1%~n1"
```

Each of these lines above are in a separate file, so I made another file to call each of these files. (Educational purposes)

All lines below are in ONE file:

```
call ImageConvert120x.bat %*
call ImageConvert80x.bat %*
call ImageConvert50x.bat %*
```

Now, when I highlight over multiple images, and drop it onto this file where it's calling each of them, it only converts the top one. I would like it to be able to convert multiple images at a time after highlighting them and dropping it onto the batch file.

This should be able to work for ALL file types.

EDIT:

I've added:

```
for %%i in (%*) do (
call ImageConvert120x.bat %*
call ImageConvert80x.bat %*
call ImageConvert50x.bat %*
)
```

But it will take the first image, and try it again and replace it again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1244045/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `for` translates `%*` (list of files) to `%%i` (single file), so it's of no use to `call ImageConvert120x.bat %*` (with the list of files). Use `%%i` (one single file at a time):

```
for %%i in (%*) do (
  call ImageConvert120x.bat %%i
  ...
)
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for helping and explaining. I was really confused when I was directed to a question asking for the same thing but using pngcrush. Thank you very much.