# Jpegtran - Drag and drop batch file for multiple files

Tags: linux, batch-file, drag-and-drop, desktop, jpegtran

Is it possible to create a batch file capable of optimizing multiple images at once? Drag and drop multiple .jpg files on it? (and have the output be something like image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg in a separated folder named "Optimized"?

If jpegtran is not the perfect tool for doing this, then I am open for any other suggestion. Maybe imagemagick is a better tool for this?

Comment: Interesting but I think it's unlikely in batch.

Comment: Files dragged-and-dropped onto a batch file appear as its arguments, which can be accessed by `%1`, `%2`, `%3`, or all at once, `%*`; type `call /?` into a command prompt window and read the help, and also reference this resource: [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)...

Answer (score 1):

This code below allows you to drag and drop files onto it and then copies them to `%userprofile%\Desktop\Optimized` on your desktop.

```
@echo on
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "params=!cmdcmdline:~0,-1!"
set "params=!params:*" =!"
set count=0
for %%G IN (!params!) do (
  set /a count+=1
  set "item_!count!=%%~G"
  rem echo !count! %%~G
)
for /L %%n in (1,1,!count!) DO (
  xcopy "!item_%%n!" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Optimized"
)
pause
exit
```

Check out [THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243240/drag-and-drop-batch-file-for-multiple-files)

I tested it on `.jpeg` and `.png` files apparently there is a limit of 2048 characters as well. see the link for more info.

Comment: Apparently this is better than using the `%1,` `%2,`  `%3` method

Comment: I have tried your .bat file but as far as I can see it moves the image to Optimized folder without actually optimizing it.

Comment: By 'optimizing it' do you mean adding a number to each `.jpg`?