# Run command with drag and drop onto batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to drag and drop a file onto a batch file in order to run the below command on it. How do I go about running the command on the dropped file?

```
PotreeConverter.exe <dropped file> -o C:/output -p index
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `path` of the file, when you drop it on the `BAT`file, will be returned as a normal `%1` argument.

so :

```
@echo off
PotreeConverter.exe "%~1" -o C:/output -p index
```

You can use `%*` if you drop more then 1 file

Example :

```
@echo off

for %%a in (%*) do echo [%%a] was dropped on me 
pause
```

Comment: that won't work for file names with spaces or special characters

Comment: what will not work ? That's the only known solution to get the file name of a dropped file in bat!!!!

Comment: last time I tested and it doesn't work for strings with spaces but I forgot how I run the command. Maybe I made some mistake. But it won't work for files like `somename(a,b)` or `me&you.txt` due to the [bad file name handling in Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1243240/995714)

Comment: I don't know how you made your test ! I made a file `"fich&ier(1) test.txt"` and it work perfectly ! And again that's the only solution in BAT!!!

Comment: copy exactly the names I pasted above. Names with both spaces and comma, semicolon or ampersand won't work

Comment: Did you read the name i tested `fich&ier(1) test.txt`  it have a space and a & and () and it work !!!

Comment: yes. As I said, you must use names like `a;b.txt`, `a,b.txt`, `a&b.txt` **without spaces in their names**

Comment: Is there a variable returning the folder where the .bat file is? If I use "." it will refer to the folder of the dragged file....

Comment: Yes you can use %~p0

Comment: I do have an issue when my filename is like Last^First.zip and using move "%1" USB\ in a .bat script.  The "%1" strips out the "^" sign from the filename.  Is there a way to preserve the "^".  This is when I drag and drop onto the .bat script.

Answer (score 2):

Following this [easy guide](https://taeguk.co.uk/blog/drag-and-drop-batch-files/).

Create a batch file `test.bat` with the contents

```
@echo off
echo The full path of the file is: %1
pause
```

Drag any file onto it, you will see that `%1` is replaced with the full path for that file in quotes.

Now you know how to execute some command that takes a path to a file as an argument:

```
@echo off
some_command_that_takes_a_path_to_a_file %1
```

Comment: `%1` already contains double quotes, so no need to add them especially if the path contains spaces !